# Як правильно перекласти areal coordinates?

Tags: from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Перекладаю сайт комп'ютерної графіки. В просторах Інтернету знаходив варіант - ареальні координати, російською мовою.
Чи може бути якийсь інший варіант більш зрозуміліший при вживанні?

Додаю рисунок і опис до нього.

[image]

Рисунок 1: барицентричні координати можна розглядати як області суб-трикутників CAP (для u), ABP (для v) і BCP (для w) в межах площі трикутника АВС, через що їх також називають **areal coordinates**.

Comment: області чи площі?

Comment: Трохи виправлю ваш підпис до малюнку, бо у теперішньому вигляді  він математично незбагненний. Правильно так: барицентричні координати можна розглядати як відношення площ менших трикутників CAP (для u), ABP (для v) і BCP (для w) до площі трикутника АВС, ... 
Якщо ж вам не до вподоби площеві, ареальні, то можна вжити термін трикутні координати, адже це відношення площ трикутників.

Comment: Дякую, напевне в моєму перекладі ще багато таких неточностей)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переклад [areal](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=areal%20&dicts=all&highlight=on) на e2u

> **areal** **1.** ареа́льний 2. пло́щевий, пов’я́заний з пло́щею **3.** (*про похідну*) поверхневий

підказує такий варіант:

> Пло́щеві координати

також можна ареальні, науковіше звучить.

Comment: Я би (без словників і поглибленого вивчення) сказав би «[площинні](http://sum.in.ua/s/ploshhynnyj)» — хоча, може, різні суфікси надають різні відтінки значення, не знаю.

Comment: @Sasha тут, те що вони в одній площині чи на площині - не головне

Comment: 1-е значення там: «прикметник до площина 1, 2».

Comment: @Sasha площина чи площа вимірюється в м^2?

Comment: А, все, тепер зрозумів, у чому різниця.

Answer (score 4):

Я би не надавав перекладу цього словосполучення великого значення. Як я розумію, основне поняття, якому присвячено матеріал — це барицентричні координати. А «areal coordinates» згадуються лише як алтернативна назва чи то назва для часткового випадку, чи не так?

Тобто фразу «через що їх також називають …» можна або взагалі опустити, або залишити англійське «areal coordinates», можливо, надавши в дужках *приблизний* український переклад (а не шукати точний український відповідник терміну «areal coordinates»). В ролі кандидатів на український переклад я розглядаю «площеві координати» ([per Yola](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1424)) і «**площинні координати**» ([«площинний» є в СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ploshhynnyj); щоправда, словосполучення «площинні координати» [на практиці використовують](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22) для позначення звичайних декартових координат, але якщо згадувати їх в тексті лише один раз, як приблизний переклад в дужках для «areal coordinates», то це несуттєво).

P.S.: «[Площеві координати](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22)» Google не знає, а «[ареальні координати](//www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22)» згадує один раз — і теж (як і «площинні координати) не в тому значенні.

Comment: Готовий плюсанути якщо приберете згадку про площинні, бо не знаю як поділити площину на площину, а площу на площу - знаю

Comment: @Yola, тоді сенсу в цій відповіді не буде — лише дублювання Вашої. Можете поставити мінус і аргументувати — це буде логічно. Я ще подумаю, може, варто прибрати (але я все-таки не впевнений, що різниця між «площа» і «площина» де-факто настільки чітко виражена).